IAM role access to a single folder in S3 bucket
I want to restrict the access to a single folder in a S3 bucket, and I have written an IAM for it.
I want to make sure the users of TeamRole has list and read only access to all the folders under arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}/processed/in/compliance/*.
Is there a way I could simplify the below in to one code block?
            {
                        "Sid": "AllowComplianceTeamRole1",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                                "AWS": {"Ref": "FINEFSComplianceTeamRole"}
                        },
                        "Action": [
                            "s3:GetObject",
                            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
                        ],
                        "Resource": [
                            {
                                "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}/processed/in/compliance/*"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
            {
                        "Sid": "AllowComplianceTeamRole2",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                                "AWS": {"Ref": "FINEFSComplianceTeamRole"}
                        },
                        "Action": [
                            "s3:ListBucket",
                            "s3:ListBucketVersions"
                        ],
                        "Resource": [
                            {
                                "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}"
                            },
                            {
                                "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}/*"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Condition": {
                            "StringLike": {
                                "s3:prefix": "processed/in/compliance/*"
                            }
                        }
                    }


Rather than create a Bucket Policy on the Amazon S3 bucket, you could instead create a policy on the IAM role. This is the preferred way of granting bucket access to users and roles.
The policy on the IAM Role would be the same, but you can remove the Principal since it will automatically apply to the IAM Role where the policy is attached.
The rest of your policy seems correct (assuming you want to grant all those permissions).

you can try this
   {
        "Sid": "AllowComplianceTeamRole",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": {"Ref": "FINEFSComplianceTeamRole"}
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:ListBucketVersions"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            {
                "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}/processed/in/compliance/*"
            },
            {
                "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}"
            }
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": "processed/in/compliance/*"
            }
        }
    }

